# What distribution do these probabilities follow?

Tags: probability-distributions, pattern-recognition, random-matrices

I'm seeking a probability density function $\Lambda(n,m)$ (where $m$ is the random variable and $n$ is a parameter) describing the probabilities shown in the matrix below, which have been found through simulation: $\Lambda(n,m)$ is the probability that an $n\times n$ real matrix has precisely $m\in\{0,1,\dots,n\}$ eigenvalues with negative real part.  I was hoping someone might be able to recognize the pattern:

\begin{pmatrix}
0.5000  &  0.2500  &  0.1045   & 0.0372  &  0.0112  &  0.0029  &  0.0006 \\
0.5000  &  0.5000  &  0.3955   & 0.2500   & 0.1303   & 0.0568 &   0.0209 \\
     &  0.2500  &  0.3955  &  0.4256 &  0.3584  &  0.2471  &  0.1425 \\
& & 0.1045  &  0.2500  &  0.3586  &  0.3865  &  0.3360 \\
& & & 0.0372  &  0.1302   & 0.2471   & 0.3360 \\
& & & & 0.0113  &  0.0568   & 0.1425 \\
& & & & & 0.0029   & 0.0209 \\
& & & & & & 0.0006
\end{pmatrix}
where the $(m+1,n)$-th entry is $\Lambda(n,m)$ ($m+1$ because $m$ starts from $0$) and where the blank entries are zeros.

**Does anyone recognize this as some density function?**

---

**Here is what I've found so far:**

- Since $\Lambda(n,m)$ is a pdf over $m$, $\sum_{m=0}^n \Lambda(n,m)=1.$
- Symmetry: $\Lambda(n,m)=\Lambda(n,n-m).$
- I'm fairly certain that $\Lambda(n,0)=\Lambda(n,n)$ is a Gaussian (I can provide details if there is interest).
- When $m\not=0,n,$ $\Lambda(n,m)$ can be approximated by a Gaussian, where the approximation gets worse the longer away $m$ gets from any of the two endpoints.

Here are some logplots of $\Lambda(n,m)$ as a function of $n$ and then $m$:

[image]

[image]

Below is the first plot, but with Gaussians fits shown as well: One can see that the fits gets worse the further $m$ is from either $0$ or $n$:

[image]